# Как показать библиотеки для Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll

В общем у меня такая ситуация:

1. решил поставить VS на мини-ПК, но места на нём всего 32 (а свободного около 10)
2. чтобы не захломлять внутренню память я установил VS на флешку, но по хитрому (т.к. она сразу на съёмный носитель не хочет, то я сделал пустую папку с путём на фешку,установка пошла)
3. после установки VS не может найти 3 библиотеки: atl110.dll MSVCR110.dll MSVCP110.dll(причём на компьютере эти библиотеки пристутствуют как на системном диске, так и на съёмном)

Как же теперь это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Кароче, просто переустановил офис. Сейчас он работает без ошибок.